# Regular Expression In XML for download file

Tags: xml, regex

I need help in writing a XML :
I have a program that in .net and i load XML files into it so it will download files using the XML
This is the XML :

```
    <Software Name = "Kaspersky">
        <Address Name = "http://products.kaspersky-labs.com/products/english/special/kasp_updater">
            <File Name = "updater2.0.1.2015.1_win_en.zip" Store = "yes"/>
        </Address>  
    </Software>
```

Now i want that the XML will be able to download me this file even if the numbers in the middle(the numbers that indicate the version number) will change, so i want a regular expression that will
force the name of the file to be :

in the start of the file there will be "updater"

in the end of the file there will be "_win_en.zip"

how could i do it ? take in to consideration that there is a lot of other files that i don't want to download like the same updater but to Linux and it name is : updater2.0.1.2015.1_**lin**_en.zip
so i have to keep the start of the file name and end of the file name as i wrote earlier..
Thank you

Comment: XML can't download files. It's just a data format. You could put a regular expression there instead of a filename and hope that the software consuming it expects a regular expression, but then how would it know what files were available to match?

Comment: This XML will be loaded into a software that will download it..
so the software will download it, the XML will only "give the order"

Comment: ^ this. Also, do you mean you want to force the xml to have a certain format? E.g. for the attribute Name, only values starting with updater are allowed. You can do that with XSDs and Regex.

Comment: So this will take care of it until the "_win_en.zip" :
^updater[0-9].[0-9].[0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9]
yes?
and how i do the last part? forcing the string to end with "_win_en.zip"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go son:

`<File Pattern = "updater[0-9].[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]{4}.[0-9]_win_en.zip" Store ="yes"/>`